# UTF8 Encoding Issue

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I have the following code:

```php
    function parseMinecraftColors($string) {
        $string = utf8_decode(htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
        $string = preg_replace('/\xA7([0-9a-f])/i', '<span class="mc-color mc-$1">', $string, -1, $count) . str_repeat("</span>", $count);
        return utf8_encode(preg_replace('/\xA7([k-or])/i', '<span class="mc-$1">', $string, -1, $count) . str_repeat("</span>", $count));
    }
```

It translates a string such as `Hi §5Person` to its HTML form (with colour based class). However, when using a unicode such as `❤️` or any other, it shows as `?` in the output.

Not sure where I can go to fix this, as unicodes are often present in the end string.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

`utf8_encode` and `utf8_decode` are badly named functions which are very rarely what you want.

Let's look at the encodings you're using:

```
htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")
```

Here, you are telling [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) that your string is encoded as UTF-8. So far, so good.

```
$string = utf8_decode(...);
```

Now, you tell [utf8_decode](https://www.php.net/utf8_decode) to convert the string from UTF-8 into ISO-8859-1 encoding. ISO-8859-1 is a single-byte encoding, which can only represent 256 different characters, and certainly doesn't contain any emojis. As the manual notes:

> Bytes in the string which are not valid UTF-8, and UTF-8 characters which do not exist in ISO-8859-1 (that is, characters above U+00FF) are replaced with ?.

After performing the rest of your code, you then run this:

```
return utf8_encode(...)
```

This tells [utf8_encode](https://www.php.net/utf8_encode) to convert your ISO-8859-1 string back to UTF-8. But it's already too late, all those nice emojis that don't exist in ISO-8859-1 have already been turned into ?s, and there's no way to get them back.

---

If you take away the utf8_decode and utf8_encode calls, you will have a different problem: the PCRE regex functions (such as preg_replace) only work on single bytes by default, but in UTF-8 `§` is two bytes long. So when you replace the byte `A7`, you're replacing "half a character", leaving an invalid string.

You can fix this in one of two ways:

- Leave the regex in single-byte mode, but match the correct sequence of bytes, which is `C2 A7`; e.g. `preg_replace('/\xC2\xA7([0-9a-f])/i', ...`
- Put the regex into UTF8 mode, by adding [the `u` modifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), and referencing the Unicode code point for `§` which is `A7`; e.g. `preg_replace('/\xA7([0-9a-f])/iu', ...`

In short, try this:

```
function parseMinecraftColors($string) {
    $string = htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $string = preg_replace('/\xC2\xA7([0-9a-f])/i', '<span class="mc-color mc-$1">', $string, -1, $count) . str_repeat("</span>", $count);
    return preg_replace('/\xC2\xA7([k-or])/i', '<span class="mc-$1">', $string, -1, $count) . str_repeat("</span>", $count);
}
```

Or this:

```
function parseMinecraftColors($string) {
    $string = htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $string = preg_replace('/\xA7([0-9a-f])/iu', '<span class="mc-color mc-$1">', $string, -1, $count) . str_repeat("</span>", $count);
    return preg_replace('/\xA7([k-or])/iu', '<span class="mc-$1">', $string, -1, $count) . str_repeat("</span>", $count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this gives me:
�<span class="mc-color mc-5">Hello �<span class="mc-color mc-9">Hi ❤️</span></span>

Comment: Hey @IMSoP I'm just using a plain php variable currently, `$string = '§5Hello §9Hi ❤️';`

Comment: @CharlieJ I see the problem now. Please see the new second half of my answer.